# Rails, pjax and title tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, pjax

I have method:

```
# Set html <title>
def page_title lang
  if request.xhr?
    response.headers["X-PJAX-Title"] = t lang
  else
    @html_title = t lang
  end
end
```

It's should works, but I have troubles with russian words, in locales: `Авторизация`, in response `ÐÐ²ÑÐ¾ÑÐ¸Ð·Ð°ÑÐ¸Ñ` =)

Pjax accepts title tag in response body, but add it to each file – its doesn't DRY way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting your pagetitle in the controller like you mentioned in the controller, you can have a global pjax callback

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function(event, request) {
  var title = request.getResponseHeader('X-PJAX-Title');
  $('document').attr('title',title);
})
```

Comment: That's what I did, but I have problems with encoding.